# Link on a webpage to open instagram app

Tags: android, instagram

Is there a way to setup a link on a webpage, so that it tries to open the instagram app. (if it's installed)?

I'm trying to do this for a responsive website so I'm not in another "app".

This does not work:

```
<div>
    <a href="instagram//:media?id=434784289393782000_15903882">instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882</a>
</div>
```

EDIT: I've corrected the typo as suggested in the answers and tested on iPhone. Work fine! Thanks @Krisrak! But I'm testing on Android Galaxy Nexus and it does not work. I see 2 messages, first "You must log out in order to reset your password." then it fades out and I see another saying "Sorry, we weren't able to load that link.".

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo the href should be `://` not `//:`

```
<div>
<a href="instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882">instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882</a>
```

Comment: Good catch! (Shame one me!) But now, when I click this link, I see a little message that says "You must log out in order to reset your password." then it fades out and I see another saying "Sorry, we weren't able to load that link." I tried with another media id to be sure, same result (639290376753075414_329368156). The phone I'm testing this with is a Galaxy Nexus. Is the media id I'm using the good value?

Comment: I've tested this and it works well! I'll edit my question so that it's Android specific!

Comment: that url is for iphone only :(

Comment: I've heard something about Intent for Android? I guess I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: There was a typo in the url but that doesn't solve the problem of opening instagram on android from a web link.

Comment: how to I use an url like this one that opens in "make new story" part of the app, in a tiktok fashion let's say. I want to make a button that goes to make a story.

Answer (score 23):

**1st Method**

`<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/{USERNAME}/">Link to Instagram Page</a>`

- Ask user to select application to launch with

---

**2nd Method**

`<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>`

- If user **installed** instagram application : Directly launch page with native application
- If user **not installed** instagram application : Do nothing

---

Tested on Android 4.4 Chrome

Answer (score 5):

For Android, you can try use this ( both for Chrome and Android's browser)

```
intent://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end
```

e.g:

```
<a href="intent://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end"> test open Instagram ANDROID</a>
```

Comment: Are there any other "places" you can go in the Instagram app? The above seems to go to "mainfeed", I'm wondering if I can change that to something else like open the gallery.

Comment: @SunilD. did you find a way on how to open a Camera screen?

Answer (score 4):

For browsers in android, if you want to link to a specific instagram page, try this:

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/USERNAME/">visit our instagram page</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

Works 100% `<a href="instagram://user?username=untitled.tiff">untitled.tiff</a>`

[untitled.tiff](http://instagram://user?username=untitled.tiff)

Comment: Unfortunately the Stackoverflow editor removes the ':' from the link. But it works on Edge, FireFox, Opera, Chrome. Internet Explorer. At least on Windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, UC browser and Mozilla Firefox do not open native app via url, but , Chrome and default browser or htmlviewer in android does open the the native instagram android app

try following links in chrome browser(Android)/ native HtmlViewer :

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/p/">Open Instagram</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/p/">Open Instagram</a>

<a href="http://instagr.am/p/">Open Instagram</a>
<a href="https://instagr.am/p/">Open Instagram</a>
```

Comment: Mozilla Firefox does open native apps via URL.