# How to make Instagram "Open in app" button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, instagram

I'm doing an app in angular 1.4.2 and want to mimic the behaviour of instagram mobile web to open the app, when I tap on the button the instagram is opened, is that possible?

[image]

I already tried the solutions on older posts but none seemed to work. I don't know if it's an angular problem or that they don't work anymore.
Older posts:

- [Open Instagram from Android Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876333/open-instagram-from-android-browser)
- [Link on a webpage to open instagram app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295051/link-on-a-webpage-to-open-instagram-app)

More details of what I tried and didn't worked:

```
<a href="instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882">instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882</a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/{USERNAME}/">Link to Instagram Page</a>
<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>
<a href="intent://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end"> test open Instagram ANDROID</a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/USERNAME/">visit our instagram page</a>
<a href="instagram://user?username=untitled.tiff">untitled.tiff</a>
<a href="instagram://app">Open Instagram</a>
```

Comment: "None seemed to work" is not enough of a description of the problem. Post the code you used and what happened exactly.

Comment: Of the links you posted, 2. opens app selection (instagram / chrome), 3. works fine, 4. does, too (intent link), 5. also opens selection - tested on latest Chrome on Android 6.0.1

Comment: Well you are right, I must have being doing something wrong, now its working number 3. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried further and this link end up working.

```
<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>
```

Also I had to add to remove the "unsafe:" tag that angular was adding.

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
     $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(http|https?|local|data|instagram):/);
    }
]);
```